# Wrong result in while condition

Tags: python, while-loop

I used Python and write first while condition:

```
target = 9
guess = 0
limit = 3
while guess<=limit:
    guess = int(input('guess: '))
    guess +=1
    if guess == target:
        print("you win")
        break
else:
    print("you fail")
```

When I run this, I succeed to get result of failure:

```
guess: 1
guess: 2
guess: 3
you fail
```

But when I enter 9 I get a wrong answer:

```
guess: 1
guess: 9
you fail
```

Could someone tell me why I do not get `"you win"` as result here? I failed to find an error in format.

And why I am able to enter only two guesses when I use `guess < limit`?

Comment: You use `guess` both as a variable to hold input and as a counter - when you enter `9`, you then add `1`, which makes `guess == 10`, that's wrong but `guess` is no longer `<=limit`. This is a classic case of testing to check if your code does what you expect, instead of testing what happens in other cases; you see that 1,2,3 has the expected behaviour and you conclude your code must be correct, but you don't try other patterns like 1, 1, 1 or 9, 9, 9, etc. Given that 1, 9 yields an unexpected result, you should just step through and keep an eye on your variable values.

Comment: Also note that your question really has nothing to do with PyCharm. It's like asking a question about an html web page and saying you wrote the html in Notepad, that's really not relevant.

Comment: Understand. Thank you for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ***guess*** variable is the global variable that is changing inside the loop because you are initializing new value entered by the user, if the user enters value more then limit, loop stops. so I changed the name of the global variable.

```
target = 9
count = 0
limit = 3
while count<limit:
    guess = int(input('guess: '))
    if guess == target:
       print("you win")
       break
    else:
       print("you fail")
    count+=1
```

Comment: Should be `while count <= limit` as OP wants 3 tries

Comment: The initial value of count is 0, it will run 3 times!

Comment: Some explanation should be added to supplement the code in the answer.

Comment: Oh, I guess, this simple code doesn't need much explanation.

Comment: At least an explanation of what went wrong with OP's code. A code-only answer is rather superficial